Question about some engineering solutions in control moment gyro ECP Model 750
My attention was drawn to this design of the control moment gyroscope: Model 750 Control Moment Gyroscope. Fact sheet. Next I will give a picture from this document:

The extended description contains additional information (ECP MODEL 750 USER MANUAL). This gyroscope consists of a base, a series of frames, motors, sensors and braking mechanisms. A special feature of this gyroscope is that despite 4 axes for rotation, only two of them are driven - the internal one (with a high-inertia rotor) and the rotation of its outer ring. Below are excerpts from the document.
[Page 28]

2.2 Electromechanical Plant
2.2.1 Design Description
The plant, shown in Figure 2.2-1, consists of a high inertia brass
rotor suspended in an assembly with four angular degrees of freedom.
The rotor spin torque is provided by a rare earth magnet type DC motor
(motor #1) whose angular position is measured by a 2000 count per
revolution optical encoder (encoder #1). The motor drives the rotor
through a 3.33:1 reduction ratio which amplifies both the torque and
encoder resolution by this factor. The first transverse gimbal
assembly (body C) is driven by another rare earth motor (motor #2) to
effect motion about axis #2. The motor drives a 6.1:1 capstan to
amplify torque between the adjoining bodies C and B. A 1000 line encoder
with 4x interpolation is mounted on the motor to provide feedback of
the relative position of bodies C and B with a resolution of 24,400
counts per revolution. The subsequent gimbal assembly, body B, rotates
with respect to body A about axis #3. There is no active torque
applied about this axis. A brake, which is actuated via a toggle
switch on the Controller box, may be used to lock the relative
position of A and B and hence reduce the system degrees of freedom. The
relative angle between A and B is measured by Encoder #3 with a
resolution of 16,000 counts per revolution. Finally, body A rotates
without actively applied torque relative to the base frame (inertial
ground) along axis #4. The axis 4 brake is controlled similarly to
the axis 3 brake and the feedback resolution is again 16,000 counts
per revolution.

[Page 45]

4.5 Sensors
There are four incremental rotary shaft encoders used in the Model
750. Encoders 1 and 2 are driven directly off the motor shafts and have an optical resolution of 500 and 1000 lines per revolution respectively.

My question is addressed to those who have any experience with these or similar gyroscopes, as well as to the development engineers of such devices: why are only two axes used as drive axes, why these particular ones, are these two axes enough to control the three-dimensional position of the body, , why are they used incremental encoders and not absolute ones?
Just some little edit: I made this model in SolidWorks, there are two drives, but the movement is on all four axes.


The linked pdf does not say that there are only two motors in this device. It doesn't appear to say that the encoders are incremental. PDF doesn't appear to say that it can simulate / control all three axes of a body. You can improve the question by [edit]ing it to quote the relevant text from the pdf. Also, remember that this is an educational device.

@AJN I have added information. Can you please tell the models of gyroscopes that are not educational, or are such devices developed individually each time for a satellite?


My question is addressed to those who have any experience with these or similar gyroscopes, as well as to the development engineers of such devices:

Disclaimer: I am not one of them.

why are only two axes used as drive axes,

The inner most moving frame with the motor generates and maintains the spin of the wheel. It is essential since friction would otherwise slowly bring the wheel speed to zero.
When wheel is spinning, the angular momentum vector of the wheel is shown in the annotated picture below as the blue axis marked S, H. This axis is always perpendicular to the wheel face.
When the wheel is used as a Reaction wheel, the spin speed of the wheel varies and the angular momentum vector magnitude changes. This change in angular momentum vector is marked in pink as ΔH1. The rate of change of angular momentum ΔH1/Δt is the torque produced and it is in the same direction as H. The reaction to this torque is felt by the spacecraft and it can be used to control it. To control the orientation of a spacecraft, we need to be able to generate torque not just about the S axis, but all three axes. So (generally speaking@) we need at least three reaction wheels whose spin axes are pointing in three different directions$.

When the wheel is used as a fixed speed, single gimbal control moment gyro (FS SG CMG), then the wheel speed is fixed. This means that magnitude of the angular momentum H is fixed. To create ΔH/Δt, we need to vary its direction. This is done by the motor fixed on the G axis. The change in the angular momentum vector is then in the direction shown as ΔH2. This direction is parallel to and is marked as T axis in the picture. Here too, at any given instant, a single FS SG CMG can generate torque only in one direction. so we need at least three of them@ in a spacecraft to be able to generate torque arbitrarily in all three directions$.

why these particular ones

Well, the spin motor needs to be the closest to the wheel body. The CMG motor needs to be in the frame just outside the spin frame. that leaves the outermost two frames as the free frames.

are these two axes enough to control the three-dimensional position of the body

No@. But, ignoring the two driven frames, this device has only two free frames and hence is not exactly same as a spacecraft which has three free degrees of (angular) freedom. If we can simultaneously operate this device in both reaction wheel mode and SG CMG mode, then that would allow to control the two free frames.
@ There exists literature where complex control equations allow us to control spacecrafts where torque can be generated only in one or two directions at a time.
$ Not really three different directions, but three directions which "span" three dimensional space.

why are they used incremental encoders and not absolute ones

I am not sure, but, the software that comes with these kits usually define the initial angle as zero and accumulate the increments to keep track of the angle and speed. My guess is that absolute encoders are probably expensive and require calibration to set the zero position. It doesn't add any value to the kit.

why are only two axes used as drive axes,

There are also dual gimbal CMGs. SG CMGS are more prevalent AFAIK.

Can you please tell the models of gyroscopes that are not educational

I do not know.

or are such devices developed individually each time for a satellite.

I do not know.

Thank you! Did I understand correctly that ideally there should be either reaction wheels (one wheel per corresponding axis) or a control moment gyro with a motor on each of the axes? And check out the gif I added to the question.

Yes, one wheel per axis is usually required. But repair being difficult in space, spacecrafts usually go with four or more wheels and use appropriate math to convert the 3 dimensional demanded-torque to N wheel accelerations (or N gimbal rates in the case of CMGs).

@ayr Yes, I recognize a similar gif in another question posted in SE a few days ago.

Yes, there I just wanted to reproduce the gyroscopic effect, and in the second model to see how it would move with two motors and 4 degrees of freedom.
